# How to add values from dataframes to another dataframe for right index?

Tags: python, pandas

I want to add a column 'direction' to df_trials with value 7 for x>0, y=0 and 8 for x=0,y>0.
I have dataframes for every direction seperatly.

```py
df_trials_direction_7 = df_trials_clean[df_trials_clean["target_x"] > 0]
df_trials_direction_7 = df_trials_direction_7[df_trials_direction_7["target_y"] == 0]
df_trials_direction_7['direction']=7

df_trials_direction_8 = df_trials_clean[df_trials_clean["target_x"] == 0]
df_trials_direction_8 = df_trials_direction_8[df_trials_direction_8["target_y"] > 0]
df_trials_direction_8['direction']=8
```

df_trials_clean looks like this:

```py
user trial target_x target_y
1    2     10       0
     3     0        5
2    1     4        0
     4     0        6
```

I've tried:

```py
df_trials_clean['direction']=df_trials_direction_8['direction']
df_trials_clean['direction']=df_trials_direction_7['direction']
```

but this only adds 7 to the column and puts NaN at the places where 8 should be.
I've simplified it a bit, there are 8 directions in total so simply replacing NaN by 8 won't work.

The desired output is:

```py
user trial target_x target_y direction
1    2     10       0        7
     3     0        5        8
2    1     4        0        7
     4     0        6        8
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use boolean condition and `np.select`, this way if a row meets neither condtion, 0 will be assigned.:

```
cond1 = (df['target_x'] >  0) & (df['target_y'] == 0)
cond2 = (df['target_x'] == 0) & (df['target_y'] >  0)

df['direction'] = np.select([cond1, cond2], [7, 8])
df
```

Output:

```
            target_x  target_y  direction
user trial                               
1    2            10         0          7
     3             0         5          8
2    1             4         0          7
     4             0         6          8
```